# How to save or keep data to be used in my settings page after sign in using firebase google sign in, in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I have created an app which allows users to sign in using Google with the help of firebase however, i am not able to display the user email in the settings page. How can i use the user email throughout the app.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> signIn() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
       accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    );
     final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.user;
   final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(firebaseUser.uid == currentUser.uid);
    return firebaseUser;
 }

 void signOutGoogle() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    print("User Sign Out");
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the email only for the current session you can store it in a class that is available as a singleton.

If you want to store the email permanently to remember the user on the next login, use packages like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) that allow you to store values as files permanently.